# javafx: how to close unknown child stages/windows

Tags: javafx, java-8, stage, xuggle

I use this code to convert a video with xuggler:
http://www.jochenhebbrecht.be/site/2010-10-12/java/converting-resizing-videos-in-java-xuggler

The convertion works fine and the line:

```
reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeViewer(true));
```

let me view two windows with video and statistics.The problem is, after converting the windows don't close automatically and I don't know how to do it.

I changed the above line into

```
IMediaListener imL=ToolFactory.makeViewer(IMediaViewer.Mode.FAST_VIDEO_ONLY,true);
reader.addListener(imL);
```

and after the while I insert

```
reader.removeListener(imL);
            reader.close();
```

But the windows don't disappear after converting/ task finished.So I want to know how I can get access to this windows to achieve a simple stage.close().

**EDIT: I'm using Java 8**

**EDIT2:**
I now tried

```
StageHelper.getStages().size(); //-> 1
```

and

```
Iterator<Window> windows=Window.impl_getWindows();
String window_String="";
while(windows.hasNext()){
    window_String+=" |-> "+
}  
System.out.println("WINDOWS: ---->"+Window.impl_getWindows());
```

Both shows that there is just ONE window.It seems, that the windows from 
"**reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeViewer(true));**" are not in the list.

Comment: Unfornately I'm using still Java 8 and I can't change for this project.

Comment: The class `ToolFactory` is from Xuggler? But it seems like Xuggler uses Swing and not JavaFX so the correct way to get the windows is [`java.awt.Window.getWindows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--).

Comment: Thanks this did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that Xuggler uses Swing and not JavaFX so `Window.impl_getWindows()` and `StageHelper.getStages()` wont return the windows that are create with `ToolFactory.makeViewer(true)`.

So the correct way is [`java.awt.Window.getWindows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--).